# Magento 2: Add a mass action block item for a UI Component grid

Tags: magento2, admin, event-observer, uicomponent, massaction

I am trying to add a mass action item to the product grid mass action block using an observer.

Here is what I am doing but it does not seem to be working, I feel like I am missing something

**app/code/DigitalPianism/ProductExport/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="DigitalPianism_ProductExport" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

**app/code/DigitalPianism/ProductExport/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'DigitalPianism_ProductExport',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/DigitalPianism/ProductExport/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction">
        <observer name="digitalpianism_productexport_add" instance="DigitalPianism\ProductExport\Observer\AddMassExportAction" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/DigitalPianism/ProductExport/Observer/AddMassExportAction.php**

```
<?php
namespace DigitalPianism\ProductExport\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddMassExportAction extends ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        $block->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'productexport',
            [
                'label' => __('Export to CSV'),
                'url' => $block->getUrl('productExport/productexport/exportCsv')
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to add a massaction depending upon the system configuration through the observer, but the event observer doesnt work. Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: @Manashvibirla you don't need to use observers anymore, it's done directly via the UI Components (see the answers below)

Comment: I got that. But what if i want to add a massAction only if a certain configuration is selected in the System configuration ?

Comment: @Manashvibirla not sure to be honest, feel free to create a new question

Comment: Check my [module here](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/MassProductUpdate). It adds custom mass action along with the input field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question.

### For Magento 2.0

The right way to add a mass action item to the Catalog grid in Magento is by creating the following file:

`app/code/DigitalPianism/ProductExport/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <container name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="export">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">export</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export to CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">productExport/productexport/exportCsv</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </container>
</listing>
```

### For Magento 2.1

See Giel Berkers answer

Comment: Raphael Can you share download csv code

Comment: @Manoj you can find it in this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/97978/2380

Comment: When I add a `<container name="listing_top">`-node to my custom layout XML, my pagination breaks and the page loads all of my products at once. Magento 2.1.1

Answer (score 14):

Please note that since Magento 2.1.x, the XML has slightly changed. You now have to use `<listingToolbar/>` instead of `<container/>`:

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="export">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">export</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export to CSV</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">productExport/productexport/exportCsv</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
</listingToolbar>
```

Comment: What if you wanted to make this action conditional based on the given row? For example a grid with an action dropdown with actions like edit, cancel, etc, but only if the item is editable or cancelable based on ACL?