# Mass action in the grid in tab redirects to dashboard in magento2

Tags: magento2, massaction

I've a form with multiple tabs and in one tab there is a grid with mass actions.

But when i click on Submit button, after selecting the massaction, the control is redirected to dashboard.

[image]

this is the code to get the mass action

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('sku_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setTemplate('Namespace_Module::massaction_extended.phtml');
        //$this->setMassactionIdFieldOnlyIndexValue(true);
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('universalProductsGrid');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            [
                'label' => __('Remove Global SKUs'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('namespace_module/*/massDeleteSku',['id'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            ]
        );
        return $this;
    }
```

**EDIT**
I have found the problem, the form_key was not rendered in the massaction form, so temporary i added the below function in the file

magento-root/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Grid/Massaction/Extended.php

```
public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }
```

and then in the file `Namespace_Module::massaction_extended.phtml`

replaced `<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>` with

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php //echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

But now my problem is how do i change this in my module block, instead of changing the core block.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using the XML to add your massaction ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97252/magento-2-add-a-mass-action-block-item-via-observer

Comment: Whats your adminhtml route id?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism - can the inner grid massaction be prepared using XML ?

Comment: @PrashantValanda - i have found the solution, can you suggest me the alternative. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add formkey using `<update handle="formkey"/>` inside your all grid related layout xml files.

ex.`module_index_grid.xml` code for test,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
   <update handle="formkey"/>

   <body> 
         //code for body
   </body>
</layout>
```

Try using this.