# Implement massactions in grid using ui_component magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, massaction

How to Implement massactions in grid using ui_component magento2. I have created my ui_component and need to implement massactions. I have also created controllers for the required paths. But, somehow it is just not working. I'm using magento 2.1 C.E.

`ui_component/test_grid.xml`

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">test_grid.test_grid.test_grid_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <action name="accept">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">accepted</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Accept</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">test/Index/Massaccept</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
</massaction>
```

`Index/Massaccept.php`

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
    use \Vendor\Module\Model\TestFactory;

    class Massaccept extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

        protected $resultPageFactory = false;
        protected $_fasctcureFactory;

        public function __construct(
            TestFactory $testFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
            ) {
            $this->_testFactory = $testFactory;
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute() {
            die("working");
            $ids = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->_testFactory->create();

            foreach($ids as $id) {
                $model->load($id);
                $model->getStatus();
                $model->setStatus('Processing');
                $model->save();         
            }
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
```

My controllers are in the path:

`Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Massaccept.php`
`Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Massreject.php`

The mass actions are visible on the grid, but are not redirecting anywhere.Redirect is not working for using above code.

All I'm getting is this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined` in `massactions.js:52`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: Add a mass action block item](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97252/magento-2-add-a-mass-action-block-item)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism : I have already gone through that solution, but it is not working in my case. My controller is not getting hit and the error that I'm getting I've mentioned in the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this. It's working fine for me.

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/index/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
```

Your controller name like MassDelete.php

This is my MassActive.php

Please refer this and change  your massaccept.php file and then check after that.

```
namespace Dedicated\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Item;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Dedicated\Grid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\CollectionFactory;

class MassActive extends \Dedicated\Grid\Controller\Adminhtml\Item
{

/**
 * @var Filter
 */
protected $filter;

/**
 * @var CollectionFactory
 */
protected $collectionFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Filter $filter
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 */
public function __construct(Context $context, Filter $filter, CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
{
    $this->filter = $filter;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
/**
 * Delete action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
    $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

    foreach ($collection as $template) {
        $template->setIsActive(true);
        $template->save();
    }

    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been changed.', $collectionSize));

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
}
```

Comment: my controller name is Massdelete.php which is inside Index directory. Now, what shall be done?

Comment: You can change the file name as well as change url here like this <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/index/massdelete"/>

Comment: I keep getting this error : `massactions.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`

Comment: Can you add you massdelete.php file ?

Comment: Now, I have kept only one action that is accept and I have put Index/Massaccept.php file right there.

Comment: I have add my MassActive.php file please change as usual in your massaccept.php file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46691/discussion-between-abhishek-dhanraj-shahdeo-and-dharmendra-jadav).

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: Thanks @divya sekar

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass path like **test/index/massdelete** and **test/index/massaccept** in below arguments.

```
 <action name="reject">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">rejected</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reject</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/MassDelete"><item/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reject items</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to reject selected Requests?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action name="accept">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">accepted</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Accept</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">test/Index/Massaccept</item>                        
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
```

You have to replace with below code,

```
 <action name="reject">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">rejected</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reject</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="test/index/massDelete"><item/>
                <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reject items</item>
                    <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to reject selected Requests?</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
    <action name="accept">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">accepted</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Accept</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">test/index/massAccept</item>                        
            </item>
        </argument>
    </action>
```

**Your controller file path should be MassDelete.php and MassAccept.php**

Comment: `massactions.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`

Comment: clear var and remove cache

Comment: Did that already, I have even compiled the source, cache is disabled

Comment: have you changed filename and update your xml code based on above post?